# Echo top 5 appearing words on page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, count

Is there a function or plugin to get the top 5 most appearing words on a page? I am building a website with dynamic content and I want to check for most appearing same words.

For example, the word 'Spain' is on the page around 12 times and the word 'Netherlands' for around 8 times. I want to have a function to check this automatically and echo this.

Comment: would you like to count the words on the backend (PHP/Wordpress) or frontend (JavaScript) ???

Comment: I am voting to close this as this either: 1. Too broad. 2. Asks for recommendations of off-site resources. P.s. Please don't take it personally, you have the answer, but curation still needs to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how useful it would be. You end up with meaningless words.

```js
let text = document.querySelector('#input').innerText.split(/\s/);
let counts = text.map(w => w.toLowerCase()).reduce((acc, cv) => {
  if (cv.length > 0)
    acc[cv] = acc[cv] + 1 || 1;
  return acc;
}, {});
text = Object.keys(counts).sort((a, b) => counts[b] - counts[a]).slice(0, 5);
console.log(text);
```

```html
<div id="input">
  <p>
    Is there a little function or plugin to get the top 5 most appearing words on a page? I am building a website with dynamic content and I want to check for most appearing same words.
  </p>
  <p>
    For example: The word 'Spain' is on the page for around 12 times and the word 'Netherlands' for around 8 times. I want to have a function to check this automatically and echo this.
  </p>
</div>
```

**Filtering Added**

We can filter the array before counting words, so you can add whatever you like to the `filters` array to get rid of those words. I probably should have thought of that to begin with...

```js
const filters = ['a', 'to', 'the', 'for', 'i'];
let text = document.querySelector('#input').innerText.split(/\s/);
let counts = text.map(w => w.toLowerCase()).filter(w => !filters.includes(w)).reduce((acc, cv) => {
  if (cv.length > 0)
    acc[cv] = acc[cv] + 1 || 1;
  return acc;
}, {});
text = Object.keys(counts).sort((a, b) => counts[b] - counts[a]).slice(0, 5);
console.log(text);
```

```html
<div id="input">
  <p>
    Is there a little function or plugin to get the top 5 most appearing words on a page? I am building a website with dynamic content and I want to check for most appearing same words.
  </p>
  <p>
    For example: The word 'Spain' is on the page for around 12 times and the word 'Netherlands' for around 8 times. I want to have a function to check this automatically and echo this.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man, I will check this code. Looks good.
I will let you know if it works

Comment: One little question. The code is working but can I skip numbers? So only text being counted.

Comment: Yep, added filtering.